# Draw polygon with GUI

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, polygon, python-addin

I'm looking to make a python add in tool for ArcMap to draw a polygon.  Eventually I want the tool to also calculate the area and a bunch of other things but for now I would be happy just drawing an irregular polygon by clicking the mouse for each vertex and double clicking to close.  Anyone have a template of what that would look like as I'm horrible at coding?

The genericode produced by the add in wizzard gives the following:

```
class ToolClass3(object):
"""Implementation for Test Addin_addin.tool (Tool)"""
def __init__(self):
    self.enabled = True
    self.shape = "NONE" # Can set to "Line", "Circle" or "Rectangle" for interactive shape drawing and to activate the onLine/Polygon/Circle event sinks.
def onMouseDown(self, x, y, button, shift):
    pass
def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
    pass
def onMouseUp(self, x, y, button, shift):
    pass
def onMouseUpMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
    pass
def onMouseMove(self, x, y, button, shift):
    pass
def onMouseMoveMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
    pass
def onDblClick(self):
    pass
def onKeyDown(self, keycode, shift):
    pass
def onKeyUp(self, keycode, shift):
    pass
def deactivate(self):
    pass
def onCircle(self, circle_geometry):
    pass
def onLine(self, line_geometry):
    pass
def onRectangle(self, rectangle_geometry):
    pass
```

Comment: I've not worked with add-ins too much, so not sure on the drawing, but you could always just take advantage of all the tools that already exist for polygon drawing and let the user draw the polygon using existing polygon creation workflow options in Arcmap.  Then have your add-in let the user perform certain actions/analysis on a selected (pre-drawn) polygon. Unless you know users will only need to use one possible workflow to draw these polygons, consider letting them draw it themselves (do they need trace, how about snapping, auto-completing, multi-part, clipped centers/donut shaped, etc.)

Comment: Basically I'm making a tool to allow complete laymen to select an area of a map and it will tell them the area, drainage info, and other useful engineering information.  If I even advised them that there is an 'editing mode' they would probably be lost.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two things off the top of my head.  If you want to stick with an Add-In, you can use the `onLine`method and simply iterate through the line geometry the user creates and pass those points into an array and convert that to a polygon.  The can add segments and finishes by double clicking.

Or, another option is to make a script tool.  With a script tool, you have the option to use a [FeatureSet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z0000005r000000) as an input.  The user can draw a polygon interactively that way from the tool interface.

[image]

Comment: Sounds promising.  I was ideally looking for something similar to the cogo report functionality but if I can get the above to work I should be in business.

Comment: One disclaimer about the `onLine` method to draw a line from a Python Add-In is that it does not allow snapping, where the FeatureSet with a script tool can use snapping.  If you really need the snapping from an Add-In perspective, you may need to consider doing it in .NET.

Comment: I should be fine without snapping.  ESRI just likes to discontinue supporting things like VBA on the drop of a hat so I feel like by the time I get everything into python add ins they will stop supporting python add ins, then I will have to learn to program in another language.